# Best form field validation pattern for email at all latest browsers

Tags: html, validation, pattern-matching, email-address

I want a email validation pattern for all latest browsers. The field type must be in text, not in email.

I tried the different type of patterns like below, but not working in all browsers.

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}\b
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After apply you check in browser "Inspect element" its work on this type

```
data-regex="^[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6})$"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in input field `pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.com$"`